# Asymmetry of close voting. Shouldn't the majority decide? Proposal for 'Keep-Open' voting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

I have a popular question [Best (non-illegal!) ways to inconvenience cold callers?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9653/best-non-illegal-ways-to-inconvenience-cold-callers)

At the time of writing the question itself has 37 up-votes and a great deal of interest.

However there are 3 close-votes.

It won't take much for the question to be closed, but why?  I though the whole philosophy of Stack Exchange was to respect the opinions of the majority of the community.

The power balance is totally skewed in favour of those who want to close. Of course once a question is closed, people can vote to re-open but why wait? Why can't we vote to *keep open*?

**Proposal**

Allow **keep open** votes for use in counteracting **close votes** before the closure happens.

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/202832) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

As Shog points out in [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/208518) (linked to in the comment on the question here):

> **this has now been implemented**, though not *quite* as-requested

Basically, you'll be able to produce the effect you want by going to [the review queue](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/review/close).

I do encourage you to read through the post in full, though.